# how to retrieve thr Focus after performing setFocusable(false) in android

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have used a EditText in my project. After entering the Value in the EditText i want to click a button. If i click the Button the EditText will loss it's focus.

```
load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   description.setFocusable(false);
   }
}
```

And if i want to Change the value of that EditText means what can i do, I did the following, but it have not worked, and it couldn't get its Focus Back..

```
focus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   description.setFocusable(true);
   }
}
```

Give any suggestion to achieve this...

Answer (score 4):

Remember to call `setFocusableInTouchMode`:

```
focus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        description.setFocusable(true);
        description.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        description.requestFocus(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! I've been stuck for hours debugging... (Well, sometimes you cannot even correctly find what the problem is if the code is very complex)

Answer (score 1):

you will need to call [View.requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29) to set focus back on EditText as :

```
focus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   description.setFocusable(true);
   description.requestFocus(); //<<< get Focus on EditText
   }
}
```

Comment: @GowthAMI : focus is button and u want to set Focus on EditText on that button click right ?

Comment: @GowthAMI : can u tell me what issue u getting with my answer because this is right for requesting focus to any view

Comment: @GowthAMI : if not getting focused then first clear focus from all views on Layout and then call requestFocus . if you want to show keyboard when EditText focused then u will need to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` in Activity manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
focus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   description.setFocusable(true);// or use description.setEnable(true);
   description.requestFocus(); //<<< get Focus on EditText
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try method **setEnabled(boolean b)**  instead of  **setFocusable(boolean b)**